# How can we express the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \subseteq \alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, ordinal-numbers

Let $X$ be a set of ordinals.

If $X$ has no largest element, then 
$$
\sup X \notin X \subseteq \sup X, 
$$
and $\sup X$ is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \subseteq \alpha$.

On the other hand, if $X$ has a largest element $\max X$, then 
$$
\max X = \sup X \in X \nsubseteq \sup X,
$$
and the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \subseteq \alpha$ is $\sup X + 1$.

Is there any way to express "the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \subseteq \alpha$" that works in both cases?

One possibility would be
$$
\sup \{ \beta + 1 : \beta \in X \},
$$
but I'm looking for something more concise or elegant than that.

Comment: I've seen $\mathrm{ssup}(X)$, the *strict supremum* of $X$. I'm not a fan though.

Comment: I have seen $\sup^+(X)$ used in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathrm{rank}(X)$

Comment: Wow.  That's certainly concise and elegant!

Comment: Very efficient, but, unlike the less efficient possibility in the question, this depends on the specific representation of ordinals by sets.  It works for the usual von Neumann ordinals, but not for other possible representations.

Comment: Related: [Discussion: Differing definitions for the rank of a set](//math.stackexchange.com/q/190039)

Answer (score 1):

For a given set $X$ of ordinals,
the following formulas all refer to the same ordinal --- namely, the smallest ordinal larger than every element of $X$:
$$
\min\{\alpha \mid X \subseteq\alpha\} \\ 
\{ \gamma \mid \gamma \leq \beta \text{ for some } \beta \in X \} \\
\sup \{ \beta+1 \mid \beta \in X \}
$$

None of these are as concise as [Amit's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/117221/27343), and they also aren't as concise as I had in mind when asking the question, but they may be the best we can hope for if we are concerned about the pitfalls raised in the comments (by [Andreas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117220/how-can-we-express-the-smallest-ordinal-alpha-such-that-x-subseteq-alpha#comment300698_117221) and [jeq](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117220/how-can-we-express-the-smallest-ordinal-alpha-such-that-x-subseteq-alpha#comment675455_117221)).